# Polymorphism error on libgdx library

Tags: java, libgdx, polymorphism

Hello I have a super class Enemy

```
    public abstract class Enemy {
        protected Texture img; // Sprite image

        public void setImage(String name){
            this.img = new Texture(name);
        }
        public Texture getImage(){
            return img;
        }
    }
}
```

and now I have class Pirate that extends Enemy

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;

public class Pirate extends Enemy{
    public Pirate(){
        setImage("pirate.jpg"); // ERROR!
    }
}
```

and when I call setImage() method on my constructor I have this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:88)
    at com.mygdx.game.Enemy.setImage(Enemy.java:20)
    at com.mygdx.game.Pirate.<init>(Pirate.java:9)
    at com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher.main(DesktopLauncher.java:11)
```

So what's wrong with it? Why i get java.lang.NullPointerException?

Comment: It looks like the exception is coming from within the constructor for `Texture`, not from the code posted.

Comment: Share code for Texture class

Comment: are you sure that your `"pirate.jpg"` is found?

Comment: yes, "pirate.jpg" is found. I'm using libgdx library, so Texture class [link](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.html)

Comment: I just have eddited my code. I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

When looking at the code for the class `Texture` at line 88 you can see, that the field `Gdx.files` is called.

```
public Texture (String internalPath) {
    this(Gdx.files.internal(internalPath));
}
```

So the only thing I can think of is, that you have to initialize the field `files` yourself, by calling

```
Gdx.files = new AnyClassImplementingFiles();
```

in your init() - method (or any other method you call before using `setImage(String)`)

Texture.java: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Texture.java#L88
Gdx.java: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Gdx.java#L33

Files.java: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/Files.java

Comment: Sorry I can't understand what's my init() method? Is it main? And what's new AnyClassImplementingFiles(); ?

Comment: your init method would be a method, in which you set up everything before using it. for example the method that creates your Pirates.

Comment: The `new AnyClassImplementingFiles();` is any class that implements the interface `Files`

Comment: This should actually be done, by calling the constructor of the right backend. So if the game is a desktop game use one of the desktop backends (for example `new LwjglApplication`). This backends then initialize the fileds, because this fields are backend-dependent!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an instance of Pirate in a class that extends ApplicationAdapter. I bet that would fix the issue since it would initialize the file system. You should already be doing so but I can't tell from the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should show us, how you actually start the game.

A libgdx project usually is made of different parts:

1. The Core-Project, containing all the logic
2. The Backend-Projects, which define how t ostart the app on different backend (android, LWJGL, GWT...).

So in your core project you should have a class which extends `Game` or `ApplicationListener`.
In the backend project (for example LWJGL, a Desktop-Project) you need a `main`, which calls:

```
new LwjglApplication(new MyGame(), "Title of the Game", 1920, 1080);
```

This constructor then initializes the `Gdx.files` and other fields. This is done in the constructor of the backend, because this fileds are backend-dependent.
For example the `Gdx.files.external` on android-backend define a path to the SD-Card, while on desktop they are path to the current users home directory.

You should deffinitly read some tutorials and have a look at the demos!